# fancytree filter expanding issue

Tags: fancytree

There is a issue with fancy tree filter. I donna if its a existing bug or not

1. List item

When i try to filter the tree with search character and try to expand the resultant tree nodes. the branches doesn't displayed. But actually its expanded with branches its just that it didn't get displayed in filtered tree.
You could see the above after resetting the search.

I've browsed through the net but couldn't find any solution

how to solve this issue.